How to make milk cold without a fridge?
If I have a milt cartbox and a freezer but not fridge available, is there a way to cool the milk using the freezer? I.e. is there a specific time I can have it in the freeze that the milk gets really cold but does not freeze or the cardbox breaks?

Use the freezer to make ice. Cubes, or empty milk cartons filled with water, or plastic sandwich bags filled with water, or whatever.  Put the ice and closed milk carton together in a container, ideally an insulated one, certainly a waterproof one. (You can insulate it by wrapping a towel or sweater around it, which should make the ice last longer.) If you contain the ice in some way, leave the bag or carton open to expose the ice to the air inside the container. Make more ice in the freezer as soon as you move some into the container with the milk. Periodically, pour off some of the water that is accumulating as the ice melts. (It provides good heat conduction for cooling the milk, but will also make the ice melt faster than it would in air, so you want some but not too much.)
The milk should stay at around 0 C as long as the ice is only partially melted. Depending on the size of your container, the insulation, how much ice you add, and how frequently you open the container to use the milk, this might work for a few hours or indefinitely if you can make ice at the right pace.

I wouldn’t pour off the melted water.  You want good contact with the carton, which cubes of ice won’t give you.  I would put the carton in a plastic bag, though, so it’s protected against getting wet, if that’s a potential for problem (but leave it open, so it doesn’t trap air)

edited to clarify.

Put the milk container in a tub of water, put the tub of water in the freezer. A large tub of water will take hours to freeze solid, and will tend to freeze from the outside in. So long as you recover the milk before much of the tub of water freezes, the milk inside the tub also won't freeze.
This solution of course just slows down the whole process of the milk getting cold and ultimately freezing, but doesn't prevent it. While it will give you a longer window to get the milk before it freezes, it also means you'll be waiting longer until it's cold in the first place. I could see this being useful if you need to leave the house for several hours and want cold liquid milk on your return, but only have a freezer at your disposal and no time to make ice.
Also note that this may not be ideal for food safety reasons, as cold tap water is usually still warmer than refrigerator temperatures - a cold tub of water from the tap could warm the milk into the danger zone before the freezer cools everything to a lower temperature.

No.
Several variables mean we couldn't give you a time, and your chances of finding one out experimentally are slim.

The size and shape of the container matter, as does how full it is
How well it's in contact with already-cold things in there will also have a big effect.
Because heat flows from hot to cold, the outermost milk (especially at whatever face is underneath) will freeze before the milk further inside chills much.

You may be able to find a way to get what you want, but not trivially.  I suggest experimenting with chilling it in the freezer for a while, shaking, and then putting it back in for a bit longer.  Also if you can find one that's adjustable, there are sleeves meant for cooling wine.  You freeze those then wrap them round a wine bottle.  They'd work just as well for milk.  But you might want to put the milk in the freezer for a little while first, unless the container is smaller than a wine bottle
